# Laravel Error in Logs Doesn't Tell Me What I Need to Fix

Tags: laravel, error-handling, laravel-exceptions

I'm getting an error in my Laravel logs almost everyday, but the error message doesn't tell me which one of my views or controllers is causing the error. It's a FormRequest.php error, so I know it's a form validation error. The problem is my site has hundreds of forms so I don't know exactly which script I need to fix to make the error go away.

This is the exact error I'm getting. As you can see, the stack trace only mentions vendor files. It doesn't list any of my own scripts or give any suggestions as to what to fix.

```
[2021-09-14 21:40:16] production.ERROR: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given, called in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php on line 113 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Validation\\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given, called in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php on line 113 at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php:105)
[stacktrace]
#0 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php(113): Illuminate\\Validation\\Factory->make()
#1 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php(91): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\FormRequest->createDefaultValidator()
#2 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php(23): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\FormRequest->getValidatorInstance()
#3 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FormRequestServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\FormRequest->validateResolved()
#4 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1266): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FormRequestServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\{closure}()
#5 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1230): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->fireCallbackArray()
#6 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1215): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->fireAfterResolvingCallbacks()
#7 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(774): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->fireResolvingCallbacks()
#8 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#9 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(692): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#10 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#11 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(79): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#12 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(48): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency()
#13 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(28): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies()
#14 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies()
#15 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#16 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#17 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#18 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#19 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#21 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#23 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#25 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#27 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#28 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#29 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#30 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#32 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#34 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#35 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#36 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#37 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#38 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#39 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#40 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#41 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#42 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#44 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#45 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#46 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#47 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#48 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#49 vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#50 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#51 vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#52 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#53 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#54 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#55 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#56 public_html/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#57 {main}
"}
```

Please note: I'm not asking for a solution for how to fix "Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given." I'm asking for *where* the error in my code is so I can fix it.

Comment: Have you tried observing the errors via [Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope) or [sentry](https://sentry.io/for/laravel/) ? It would be easier fo you to debug easily

Comment: The error says, you have a class (for validation) extending FormRequest where the rules (a method in that class) returns a `null` and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess somewhere in your app you are using `FormRequest` and `rules()` method return a `null`.

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // your validation rules
    ];
}
```

The `rules` method needs to return an array.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, "Where?" So I can fix it. The site has hundreds of forms so I can't pinpoint which one it is.